# pandas how to applied fit_transform on standard scaler on group by data

Tags: pandas, group-by, normalize

There is a dataframe like this

df

| group | data | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | a |
| A | 2 | b |
| A | 3 | ad |
| A | 4 | aw |
| A | 5 | ad |
| B | 100 | ta |
| B | 200 | as |
| B | 300 | ab |
| B | 400 | ax |
| B | 500 | ad |

I would like to groupby("group") then apply standard_scaler().fit_transform() in each group

( I test with only data with a  single group in data from with this code which is working but I having problem when group data >1

```
df['data'] = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df.groupby('group').data.values.reshape(-1,1)))
```

)

I was wondering is there a way to solve this with multiple group and apply scaler in each group?

Edited:
My Desire output would be

| group | data | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | -1.414 | a |
| A | -0.7071 | b |
| A | 0 | ad |
| A | 0.7071 | aw |
| A | 1.414 | ad |
| B | -1.414 | ta |
| B | -0.7071 | as |
| B | 0 | ab |
| B | 0.7071 | ax |
| B | 1.414 | ad |

where data is transform data of normalized data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
def sc(row):
    return scaler.fit_transform(row.values.reshape(-1,1))

df.groupby('group').agg(sc)
```

Please, note that your other column is not numeric so you can not apply standard scaler on that. I tried the above code with two numeric columns.

Demonstration for two numeric columns:

```
d = '''group    data    other
A   1   a
A   2   b
A   3   ad
A   4   aw
A   5   ad
B   100 ta
B   200 as
B   300 ab
B   400 ax
B   500 ad'''
data = [x.split('   ') for x in d.split('\n') if x!='']
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
df['other'] = df['data']*2

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
def sc(row):
    return scaler.fit_transform(row.values.reshape(-1,1))

df.groupby('group').agg(sc)
```

Output:

```
    data    other
group       
A   [[-1.414213562373095], [-0.7071067811865475], ...   [[-1.4142135623730951], [-0.7071067811865476],...
B   [[-1.414213562373095], [-0.7071067811865475], ...   [[-1.4142135623730951], [-0.7071067811865476],...
```

Based on the comment:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(sc).explode().values.astype(float)
```

Comment: Did your problem solve or not?

Comment: Yes I am aware of "other" column wouldn't mean to apply standard scaler. However Beside create standard_scaler, I would like to apply fit_transform the data as well.

Comment: What??? by  fit_transform you mean that something like tfidfvectorizer?

Comment: You want to convert your text to numbers?

Comment: I mean my goal would like to normalized "data" column  based on each group.  If I apply standard_scaler.fit_transform the whole data column data would not work since there are 2 group so I would like to group by and normalize each group with their data

Comment: It is doing now!

Comment: I added an example. If it does not help, i need more explanation to help you.

Comment: Can you provide a desired output example? Also, if you do not have any thing with textual data please change that column to numeric to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I update desired output.

Comment: Look at the answer again.

Comment: That is what you want?